# Double-quote PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I know the question seems repetitive, but I think it is a special case.

At the site of my client (prestashop) attributes they added to the products (measures) with double quotation marks, but it is not ', nor this "

They used the quotation marks are: ”

The problem I emerged is that I want to call the attributes of products (through php and mysql) returns the string me as unknown character

```
Codo_90_Rosca_Hembra= ['20 x 1/2�','25 x 3/4�','25 x 1/2�','32 x 3/4�','32 x 1�','40 x 1�','40 x 1 1/4�'],
```

[image: problem quote mark]

Try using the str_replace function but had no success.

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: It is rarely a special case

Comment: This normally happens when people copy and paste from a text editor like Microsoft Word.

Comment: I had same problem and i set file encoding to UTF-8 from my code editor and it works fine, you should try it rather than changing any database data type or format.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Codo_90_Rosca_Hembra= ['20 x 1/2'.' " ']` in PHP. To match character special we used the point.